# Prevent update of note/files on disabled views

Tags: acumatica

I noticed that notes and files can be inserted/updated/deleted on grids (assume forms the same) when the grid does not allow for update, insert, or delete. Is there a way to turn this off? I am writing a custom page and want to prevent a user from modifying anything including notes and files.

My grid contains the following:

```
MyGrid.AllowInsert = false;
MyGrid.AllowUpdate = false;
MyGrid.AllowDelete = false;
```

Anything I am missing to prevent this? Is there something I can add in the aspx page of my custom screen to prevent note/file edits?

Comment: I don't think it's possible right now

Comment: Thanks. It would be nice for a future enhancement to prevent the updates on closed documents. For future reference of this article i am currently running Acumatica version 5.30.1279

Comment: something similar to vote on: https://feedback.acumatica.com/ideas/ACU-I-2271

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but here is how I removed the files and notes columns from my grid.
Inside my graph :

```
[PXRemoveBaseAttribute(typeof(PXNoteAttribute))]
[PXGuid]
public void _(Events.CacheAttached<MyDac.noteID> e) { }
```

In my case, I was reusing MyDac that already had NoteID. Since my screen was an inquiry where I wanted everything disabled, I removed the PXNoteAttribute to forbid editing files and notes.

Comment: this is a good idea for an inquiry if wanting to always disable. The problem I see with notes is on transactions or documents that go from open to closed however the notes are always editable which seems like a strange implementation. If a view or row doesn't allow update nothing on that view/row should allow changes. But I do like your solution for inquiry. Never late to the party if the party is always ongoing :)