# Can Notes and Files be disabled or hidden?

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to create a locked down stock item lookup with only a few fields that is ready-only, but I can't disable the Notes and File attachments.  I've tried setting up a role with only view access to the stock items screen and locking down the individual objects on the screen and revoking all other screens, including the hidden screens. 
I've also tried to create a generic inquiry with view only access but the initial file and note columns still appear and are not locked down.
Is there anyway to do this without creating a custom page?  I am working on v5.3.

UPDATE 3/31: Based on my comment below, does overriding the CSS class for the toolbar create any major problems or concerns?  I do understand this hides the customization and help button along with the Notes and Files.

```
<asp:Content ID="cont1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phDS" Runat="Server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .toolBarT { visibility: hidden; }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same question has been asked and it sounds like the answer currently is No (there is no way to disable the edit of notes and files).

Duplicate: 
[Prevent update of note/files on disabled views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664927/prevent-update-of-note-files-on-disabled-views)

Comment: I would flag this one as duplicate but the original question doesn't have any accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate question.  I missed the other one when searching.  Anyway, I had a thought that I'd love some additional comments.  I added some javascript to the page to hide the right toolbar.  I know this hides the customization and help buttons, but I'm trying to provide a simple display page.  Any thoughts?
**<asp:Content ID="cont1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phDS" Runat="Server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .toolBarT { visibility: hidden; }
    </style>
</asp:Content>**

Comment: I don't have any instance in my computer right now but what if we set the NoteID field to invisible ?

Answer (score 0):

To hide this buttons you have to set properties 'FilesIndicator' and 'NotesIndicator' to False (properties belongs to Form control)

Answer (score 0):

Follow up to helenira, here is a sample section (from Portal\Pages\SP\SP700000.aspx):

```
<px:PXGrid ID="gridInventoryItem" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds"
    Width="100%" SkinID="Details" AdjustPageSize="Auto"
    FilesIndicator="False" NoteIndicator="False" FastFilterID="edFindItem"
    FastFilterFields="InventoryCD,Descr" SyncPosition="True">
```

Comment: And a form entry, from AR402000.aspx (I modified the Files):  <px:PXFormView ID="BAccount" runat="server" Width="100%" Caption="Customer Summary" DataMember="BAccount" NoteIndicator="False" FilesIndicator="True" ActivityIndicator="false" ActivityField="NoteActivity" LinkIndicator="true" NotifyIndicator="true" DefaultControlID="edAcctCD">