# How can I restrict access to maintain notes and attachments to the Owner of the record?

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom module that allows an individual to submit a request.  I would like this request to have attachments and notes that anyone can view.  However, I need to limit access for adding/updating/deleting notes and attachments.

I tried restricting AllowUpdate and AllowDelete on the view containing the relevant NoteID field, but anyone can perform CRUD on notes and attachments anyway.  I looked into PXNoteAttribute but could not find any options to control access, and no PXUI attributes appeared to be relevant, although I'm not terribly proficient in the use of them yet.

How can I enable read-only access to everyone while restricting access to add/update/delete notes and attachments to the user that created the request and to the users in the role assigned to process those requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the current answer is no this is not possible. I would love to hear from anyone else who has figured this out but from experience - no luck.

Oddly enough there was a feedback post by Acumatica on this topic also today (being able to disable notes/files) which can be voted on here:
[Add ability to disable Notes & Files...](https://feedback.acumatica.com/ideas/ACU-I-2271)

I have asked a similar question on this topic:
[Prevent update of note/files on disabled views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664927/prevent-update-of-note-files-on-disabled-views)

The big issue I see with notes currently is the ability for a user to change notes even on a document that has been closed/locked from edit. We should at least have a way to have notes disabled when the row the note/file is attached to is disabled.